# Show that $f$ is a Borel measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function with
$$ x \mapsto \begin{cases}
x, \quad &\text{if} \quad x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]  \\
1-x, \quad &\text{if} \quad x \in (\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1] \\
0, \quad &\text{otherwise.} 
\end{cases} $$
One can write $f = \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}(x) \cdot x + \mathbb{1}_{(\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]}(x) \cdot (1-x) $ and clearly this function is measurable since it is a sum of measurable functions (this way it is just fine). But, would it be also ok, if I would show that the preimages are in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e.
$$ 
f^{-1}(x) = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
and in the same fashion also for $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(\{0\})$? Obviously those are again all contained in the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra, but I think that is not the correct way to do it, since one has to show, that
$$ \forall B \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}): f^{-1}(B) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}). $$ In my opinion there could be several cases for $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ arbitary: $x \in B $, $1-x \in B$, $\{0 \} \in B$, $\emptyset = B$, $\mathbb{R} \in B$, such that for all this $B$ I have to show, that the preimages are in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Please let me know, if I am on the right path!

Comment: It's actually not hard to show, as you may discover that on $[0,1]$, $f$ maps rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals. However as it typically done, one suffices to check that $f^{-1}(U)$ is Borel for every basic open $U$.

Comment: Your work is simplified by the fact that it is enough to show that $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathfrak B(\mathbb R)$ for a *generating set* of the sigma-algebra $\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)$. One such generating set is $\{(-\infty,x] : x \in \mathbb R\}$, so it's enough to show that $\{x : f(x) \leq y\}$ is Borel for all $y \in \mathbb R$. This is quite easy to show.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon My question was whether the way I was trying was okay, or if I am wrong with my assumptions, but with genereting sets I would have: $$ f^{-1}(-\infty, a] = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \leq a \}  = \mathbb{R} \backslash [0,1] \cup (\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \cup (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])  $$ I am not sure about this.

Comment: @Galois1763 Ok : your effort is good, you are on the right path, but it is not enough to show that the preimage of every single $x$ is Borel : there are functions whose preimage of each point is Borel but the function is not Borel. However, in your problem it turns out, because of the notion of generating sets, that it is in fact enough, and can be shown to imply that $f$ is Borel.  From the comment above, I am not sure you have understood what generating sets are. Can I write an answer?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I think, I messed it up in my comment, but that is the way it should work with generating sets: Let $\mathcal{G}$ a generator of $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Than it suffices to show that, for arbitary $G \in \mathcal{G}$ that we can conclude $f^{-1}(G) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$.Right? But an answer would be nice! Thank you.

Comment: @Galois1763 Right, I will try to be more detailed

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Additionally it would be really nice if you could supply an example of a function whose preimages of each point are Borel but the function itself is not Borel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb R)}$
By definition, we should be checking that for every $B \in \d$, we have that $f^{-1}(B) \in \d$.

But some niceties make things easy for us, namely the following identities :

- For any $f$ and arbitrary collection of disjoint sets $U_i$ we have $f^{-1}(\cup_{i \in I} U_i) = \cup_{i \in I} f^{-1}(U_i)$.
- For any $f$ and set $U$ we have $f^{-1}(U^c) = [f^{-1}(U)]^c$.

Both are easily proved by definition.

---

A generating set for $\d$ is given by *half intervals*, which are the subsets of $\mathbb R$ given by $H = \{(-\infty,x] : x \in \mathbb R\}$. So elements of $H$, for example are $(-\infty,0]$, $(-\infty,3.54]$, $(-\infty,-\pi]$ and so on.

The point is, that $H$ generates $\d$ in the sense that the smallest sigma-algebra containing $H$ is $\d$. Furthermore, $H$ is what we call as a $\pi$-family : if I intersect any two members of $H$, the intersection is also in $H$. For example , the intersection of $(-\infty,1]$ and $(-\infty,2]$ is $(-\infty,1]$ which remains in $H$.

Let's take an element in $H$, say $(-\infty,x]$. Then, the set $f^{-1}((-\infty,x])$ is nothing but the set $\{y : f(y) \leq x\}$.

---

> Lemma : Let $f$ be a function such that for every $x \in \mathbb R$, the set $\{y : f(y) \leq x\}$ is Borel. Then $f$ itself is Borel i.e. for any $B \in \d$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel.

Proof : Consider the sigma-algebra $\Sigma = \{B' \in \d : f^{-1}(B') \in \d\}$. This is the set of Borel sets, which we know satisfy the conditions for now. Note that $H \subset \Sigma$.

But we also know something else about $\Sigma$ : it is closed under complements and under infinite disjoint union, thanks to the two properties we mentioned at the outset. Also it is clear that $\mathbb R \in \Sigma$.

Now, this makes $\Sigma$ what we call as a *$\lambda$-system* : not quite a sigma-algebra as yet, but close. Now, we invoke the *Dynkin $\pi-\lambda$ theorem* :

> Let $S$ be a $\lambda$ system , containing a $\pi$-system $T$. Then $S$ contains $\sigma(T)$, the smallest sigma-algebra containing $T$.

That tells us, that $\Sigma$ contains $\d$, the smallest sigma-algebra containing $H$, but then $\Sigma$ is anyway contained in $\d$ as well, so we are done.

---

The result of all this, is that $f$ is Borel. Why? Let's prove it using the lemma. Pick $x\in \mathbb R$. Then we have some cases :

- If $x < 0$ then $f(y) < x$ for all $y$, so $\{y : f(y) \leq x\}$ is empty, hence Borel.
- If $x > 1$ then $f(y) > x$ for all $y$ so $\{y : f(y) \leq x\} = \mathbb R$ is Borel.
- If $x \in [0,1]$, then of course $\{y : f(y) \leq x\}$ contains $[0,1]^c$, which is Borel. Apart from this, we break into cases : if $y \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ with $f(y) \leq x$ then $y \leq x$ i.e. $y \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,x]$. Similarly, if $f(y) \leq x$ with $y \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q^c$ then $y \geq 1-x$. This makes up $[1-x,1] \cap \mathbb Q^c $. Thus :
  $$
  \{y : f(y) \leq x\} = [0,1]^c \cup \left(\mathbb Q \cap [0,x]\right) \cup \left([1-x,1] \cap \mathbb Q^c\right)
  $$
  a union of Borel sets, hence Borel.

Thus, we get that $f$ is Borel.

---

Now, a common misconception is that if for every $x$, if $\color{red}{\{y : f(y) = x\}}$ is Borel, then $f$ is Borel. This is false.

The reason? Well, the family of singleton sets $\{x\}$ don't generate $\d$, for starters. Then it doesn't even form a $\pi$-family. Finally, a Borel measurable set has more regularity, in the sense that sets that usually are indexed (or decided) by infinite sequences (like the real numbers, if treated with the decimal expansion as an infinite sequence of digits) aren't Borel because they behave far too irregularly. (More on that, but in little more detail, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253786/intuition-behind-the-non-borel-lusin-example)).

Edit : The family $H$ may look like it too is parametrized by the real numbers, but using density of rationals, you can see that a function being Borel measurable must be a result of "countable" decision i.e. decide it at the rationals and you get it everywhere.

For a counterexample, we use the Cantor set, the most fundamental set when it comes to Lebesgue measurability, along with a standard set called the *non-measurable set*. The Cantor set itself is closed, hence Borel, but we can play with it nicely.

In [this page](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/lebesgue-but-not-borel), there is a good explanation on what's happening :essentially, the Cantor function is a bijection, so every set of the form $\{x : f(x) = y\}$ is a singleton hence Borel. But the problem is that the non-measurable set which sits inside $[0,1]$, that causes problems.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a simpler example, because looking for something non-Borel yet Lebesgue measurable is in itself a topic that is difficult to discuss.

Comment: First thank you, very helpful! I just have a follow-up question: You say "The result of all this, is that the work you've done basically establishes that f is Borel". Which part of my work do you mean? I am a little confused.

Comment: That statement was ambiguous : I will rescind it. I apologize : I don't think I borrowed anything from your attempt in that case. I thought you had computed $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ for each $x$, but turns out you had not only though about it and asked if it was enough that each such set was Borel. This answer covers those concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifikation! I was at first, just confused with the question, if it is possible to show the measurability of this concrete function $f$ via $f^{-1}(x) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $f^{-1}(1-x) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f^{-1}(0) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Galois1763 Yes, as mentioned, the measurability requires more than just checking those things.I erred in assuming you had computed these, because it would have made my job easier, but it still gave me something to clarify. Thanks

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank You!

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Welcome! (I assume you are thanking me for the answer here!)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes! I have also seen some of your very good answers. Please have a look at some of my answers you have some time :)

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Sure, I will take a look over the weekend. Actually, I don't write too many answers  nowadays, I'm more into meta work on the site, like closing questions, conversing with new users and so on. It's all being done to give back to the site that has given me so much.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I see. You have contributed so much as I have seen. I am a beginner. Also, I have created a discord server for combinatorial discussion and problem-solving. Probably you would like to join. https://discord.gg/aDpQdu7VBA

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya I'd love to, you know. But unfortunately, I'm juggling too many things at one time : there's MSE work,  there's research work and there's some family work as well that needs to get done each day. While I cannot commit myself to your discussion, I will certainly advertise it on my chatroom page so that anyone visiting there can take a look. Thank you so much for considering me for joining that chatroom, very much appreciated.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon May I join your chatroom?

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Please do so, the link is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi), thanks.